# What's the difference between "awesome thanks" and "thanks very much"?

Tags: phrases

I've found "awesome thanks" in a forum reply. I wonder if there is difference between these two expressions?

> - awesome thanks
> - thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if the person who wrote this reply hasn't used punctuation at all. The reply would look correct like this:

*Awesome! Thanks!*

The words **awesome** and **thanks** used together as a phrase don't make sense.

Comment: I suppose you could say 'Awesome thanks' to mean that your thanks were of an unusually abundant kind.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: It crossed my mind too, but I've never heard of these two words combined together. I believe the most likely explanation for the appearance of this post is the poster's negligence in terms of punctuation.

Comment: Yes, could be. Who knows?